Should uniqueness validation be on the database level or backend codebase level in data import
There is a kinda ETL task of importing data from csv to the database in project with legacy codebase and legacy database**. Data should be validated before persisting to database.
Validation includes validation per row, such as data format checking, mandatory field checking etc., and global uniqueness validation.
In the respect of global uniqueness validation, the current database table, where data to be imported to, is in the following state:

There is no unique constraint with composite key
The table is already way big
data is frequently queried
data import happens frequently as well

Question is about the design of global uniqueness validation : Should global validation be done in the backend codebase or mainly by adding unique constraint to the database?

It makes sense to validate data before inserting it into the database, but for sanity, it the table should have a uniqueness constraint and external validation is not sufficient.
If the table does not have a unique constraint, then there is a big risk of non-unique data being inserted and corrupting the table.  Even if it is externally validated, there could be a race condition that allows it anyway.  This is why the database has constraints in the first place.
Externally validating the data is a good idea because if you attempt to insert invalid data into a database with a constraint, the insertion will fail; it would be better to catch this ahead of time before you try a big import action and then have all or most of it fail.
On the other hand, if you have known unclean data, it might make sense to insert it into a blank unconstrained scratch table and then incrementally clean the data, correcting flawed and duplicate entries before attempting to import it into the production table.  It may be easier and more reliable to correct the data with the database tools than with an external validation tool.
However, if you already have a production table without constraints, applying the constraints could be a costly and error prone operation and it might be a good idea to test this on a non-production system first, and possibly try to correct the production table during a low activity time or find a way to incrementally apply it after correcting any discovered issues in the test system.
This is similar to the question, should validation be done in the user front end or the database?  Answer is both.  Validate in the user front end so the user gets instant feedback before submission.  Validate in the backend for security reasons and because there's no guarantee the front end validation was actually done, and race conditions that only the database can see.


Question is about the design of global uniqueness validation : Should global validation be done in the backend codebase or mainly by adding unique constraint to the database?

The database is the backend.
It's not unusual that, for various reasons, the same validation has to be done in multiple places or in places which might seem non-ideal.
It might seem inefficient for the same criteria to be checked multiple times, but honestly, programmer error is a frequent cause of data corruption, including errors in applying the first line of validation, so it's quite normal for validation to be applied seemingly-redundantly over multiple stages of a data pipeline.
There can also be subtle differences to each validation check. For example, the client-side of a feeder application will check whether a single batch of data contains duplicates, whereas the database will check across every batch ever stored before. So even though the rules of the check are the same in each place, the data to which it is being applied is not necessarily the same.
Record keys, and an analysis of their cardinality, are very fundamental to retrieval and processing in a database context, so I would always enforce this as a unique constraint in the database (as well as any other validation on the client-side) unless there was a very specific performance reason found not to do so.
